# Alphabetize queried Music Files in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, alphabetical

Ok so im making a media player app for android. everything was ok until now. so far i have a list view that shows all .mp3 files on ur sdcard(internal and external) and when playing show a music visualizer. but i cant for the life of me alphabetize the list. everything is dynamic so xml doesnt work here.

```
 public class MusicPlayerActivity extends Activity {
  ListView musiclist;
  Cursor musiccursor;
  int music_column_index;
  int count;
  private Intent aIntent;
  public static String filename;
  private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        init_phone_music_grid();
        mRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(mRelativeLayout);
        mRelativeLayout.addView(musiclist);

  }

  public void init_phone_music_grid() {
        System.gc();

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
        };

        Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

        musiccursor = managedQuery(allsongsuri, projection , selection, null, null);

        count = musiccursor.getCount();
        musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
        musiclist.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);

  }
  private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
              System.gc();
              music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
              musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
              filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
              aIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AudioFX.class);
              aIntent.getStringExtra(filename);
              startActivity(aIntent);
        }
      };

     class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private Context mContext;

      public EfficientAdapter(Context c) {
          mContext = c;
      }
          public int getCount() {
                return count;
          }

          public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
          }

          public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
          }

          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              System.gc();
              String id = null;
              TextView tv;
              if (convertView == null) {
              tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
              } else{
              tv = (TextView) convertView;
              }
              musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
              music_column_index = musiccursor
              .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
              id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
              tv.setText(id);
              tv.setTextSize(20);
              return tv;
              }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER`, like this:

```
String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
musiccursor = managedQuery(allsongsuri, projection , selection, null, sortOrder);
```

Comment: that worked! i would vote up but not enough rep. but thanks just the same

Answer (score -1):

Showing the title inside the getView method won't get a alphabetized list.

Inorder to alphabetize the list **get all the music titles** into a String array or an ArrayList
**Alphabetize them manually and pass that String array to EfficientAdapters Constructor** and store it locally and use them according to the lists position.

like

```
 class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context mContext;
  private String values[];

  public EfficientAdapter(Context c, String[] a) {
      mContext = c;
      values = a;
  }
      public int getCount() {
            return count;
      }

      public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
      }

      public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
      }

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          System.gc();
          String id = null;
          TextView tv;
          if (convertView == null) {
          tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
          } else{
          tv = (TextView) convertView;
          }

          id = values[position];


          tv.setText(id);
          tv.setTextSize(20);
          return tv;
          }}}
```

Hope this helps.....

Comment: The files had already been passed to the Efficient Adapter and only needed to be alpahbetized.